# Count leave attributes Hierarchical oralce

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables as follows:

```
==============================          ==============================                                  
Directories                             Items
==============================          ==============================
ID    |Name         |Parent             ID    |Name         |Directory
1     |All          |null               1     |Simpson      |6
2     |Movies       |1                  2     |Avatar       |5
3     |Clips        |1                  3     |Tom&Jerry    |6
4     |Games        |1                  4     |CoD          |7
5     |Action       |2                  5     |CS           |7
6     |Cartoon      |2                  6     |NFS          |8
7     |Shooter      |4                  7     |Halo         |7
8     |Racing       |4                  8     |F4           |8
9     |Music        |3                  9     |Thriller     |9
                                        10    |Beat it      |3
```

I want to get results to see how many items in each directory in the Directories
table above, I can only count on 1 specific Directory, but to use one query for all categories is not successful, so how should I do, thanks.

```
================================
Result
================================
ID    |Name         |Items Count
1     |All          |10
2     |Movies       |3
3     |Clips        |2
4     |Games        |5
5     |Action       |1
6     |Cartoon      |2
7     |Shooter      |3
8     |Racing       |2
9     |Music        |1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all the descendants use [`connect by`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm).